# Is there ever a reason to overwrite an array variable with one of its own elements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've recently "inherited" a PHP web app that uses a mySQL database as part of its backend. While going through the code, I came across a block that absolutely puzzled me.

```php
$results = array();
$results[] = $mysqli_result->fetch_array();
$results = $results[0];

return $results;
```

So I get that the first two lines are initializing an empty array and assigning the first row  of results from a previous query to that new array. But the third line doesn't make sense to me. As I understand it, `fetch_array()` only grabs one row at a time; I can't think of any reason to have the `$results = $results[0];` line. The best I can come up with is that it's leftover code from when `mysql_result` was removed.

Is there any reason to have this third line?

Comment: @treyBake There is some difference between the (now deprecated) `mysql_result` function and `mysqli_result`. However, my question was not about that function, but the line after the one `mysqli_result` appears on. I believe the answer below has confirmed my suspicion that it serves no purpose.

Comment: `@mysqli_result->fetch_array();` returns only one row of the full set of results. See [the link here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: new line of questioning xD -- what does `var_dump($results)` (before the `$results[0]` assignment)  show? As it may be used to get first column or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no reason. This is just an example of a "cargo cult code". When you don't know how to do something properly, you just copy/paste some existing code without real understanding whether it is necessary or not.

Of course it makes no sense to create an array, then create a new element in this array, and then reassign this array variable with the first element. Instead, just assign a variable:

```
$result = $mysqli_result->fetch_array();
```

Or - better - since this variable is returned right after the assignment, simply return it right away, as the `$result` variable isn't going to be used anywhere else.

```
return $mysqli_result->fetch_array();
```

Comment: Or `return $mysqli_result->fetch_array();` since it's returned just after